# C# - Convert delimited string array w/ duplicates to dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Given

```
string[] array = new string[]
{
   "Sample1:foo",
   "Sample2:bar",
   "Sample1:foo1"
}
```

I know I can convert it to a dictionary this way:

```
Dictionary<string, string> whatever = new Dictionary<string, string>
foreach (string s in array) do...
  string sampleNumber = s.Substring(0, indexOfColon);
  string fooOrBar= s.Substring(indexOfColon + 1);
  whatever[sampleNumber] = fooOrBar;
```

And this will prevent an aggregate exception being thrown when a duplicate key is added (although overriding the key, which is fine in this case). Can I do this with LINQ? I am trying something along the lines of:

```
Dictionary<string, string> whatever = array.ToDictionary(
 key => key.Split(':')[0], value => value.Split(':')[1]);
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a lookup beforehand?

Comment: In the case you want to keep the duplicates, you can use `List<Tuple<string, string>>` with a one-liner `List<Tuple<string, string>> whatever = array.Select(key => new Tuple<string, string>(key.Split(':')[0], key.Split(':')[1])).ToList();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> whatever =
    array
        .Reverse()
        .GroupBy(key => key.Split(':')[0])
        .SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))
        .ToDictionary(key => key.Split(':')[0], value => value.Split(':')[1]);
```

It gives:

[image: whatever]

Or you could do this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> whatever =
    array
        .Aggregate(
            new Dictionary<string, string>(),
            (d, v) => { d[v.Split(':')[0]] = v.Split(':')[1]; return d; });
```

Same result.

Comment: Worked perfect.

Comment: Great idea! An alternative, possibly shorter method than using reverse and select many, is to just use Last(), not sure about the time difference, but `var whatever = array.GroupBy(p => p.Split(':')[0]).ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Last().Split(':')[1]);`.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL - I like your approach, but I do try to choose options that avoid `.Last()` or `.First()`. I know it doesn't matter with a `.GroupBy(...)` but I like keeping a good habit.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is definitely not a `Dictionary<string, string>` because keys are duplicated. It can be a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, but IMO it's much more like a a `ILookup<string, string>`:

```
var result = array
            .Select(a =>
            {
                var parts = a.Split(':');
                return new
                {
                    Key = parts[0],
                    Value = parts[1]   //maybe you need to check something here
                };
            })
            .ToLookup(o => o.Key, o => o.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you deal with the value , maybe you can try this:

```
var list = array.Select(m => new { Key = m.Split(':')[0], Value = m.Split(':')[1] })
            .GroupBy(m => m.Key)
            .ToDictionary(m => m.Key, m => string.Join(",", m.Select(p => p.Value)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sad how nobody cares about performace. Wasteful allocations, wasteful calculations. I tested accepted answer against this code on strings with 50% key collisions:

```
char[] separatorArray = { ':' }; // do not create new array on every single item of the array
HashSet<string> dedupl = new HashSet<string>();

var res = array
    .Select(s => s.Split(separatorArray))
    .Where(x => dedupl.Add(x[0]))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

it is roughly 2,5x faster and uses half of the memory (I measured top memory usage).